# video.js not playing hls stream in firefox

Tags: video.js

I was trying to play hls Stream using video.js (v8.5.3) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Player</title>
  <link href="./assets/css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="900"
    height="450"
    poster="./assets/imgs/mp_logo.png"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8632/live/v1/index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="./assets/js/video.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

when testing on firefox i get:

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) Playback cannot continue. No
> available working or supported playlists.

On chrome it plays without any problem .

What could be the issue that prevents firefox from running the hls stream ?